# Inconsistencies in looping through and creating reports

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database with 5 tables, 3 queries, 3 reports (the queries are the recordsets) and three reports each showing the several fields on the recordsets. The problem is, even though they have the same code, one of the sub routines has inconsistent results. It is like it is cycling through each supervisor and creating a report and then doing it again, it's caught in a loop and I can't see where the issue is. Hoping someone can help.

```
Private Sub cmdFedInvest_Click()
Dim x           As String
Dim y           As String
Dim StrSQL      As String
Dim stWhereStr  As String 'Where Condition'
Dim stSection   As String 'Selection from drop down list
Dim stfile      As String
Dim stDocName   As String
Dim StrEmail    As String

StrSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW [qryActT8_Sup].[Sup], [qryActT8_Sup].Sup_email " & _
"FROM [qryActT8_Sup];"
    y = Year(Date)

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim qdTemp As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdTemp = db.CreateQueryDef("", StrSQL)
Set rst = qdTemp.OpenRecordset()

If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
    MsgBox "No data available for the Ledger Process routine."
Else
    Debug.Print rst.Fields.Count
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        x = rst![Sup]
        StrEmail = rst![Sup_email]
        stDocName = "FedInvest - ISSR - T8 Recertification Report"
        stWhereStr = "[qryActT8_Sup].[SUP]= '" & x & "'"
        stfile = Me.txtLocationSaveFI & "\" & x & " - " & y & " FedInvest Recertification.pdf"
        DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , stWhereStr
        'DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, StrEmail, , , "2016 FedInvest Recertification", ""
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, stfile
        DoCmd.Close acReport, stDocName
        rst.MoveNext
   Loop
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You both open the report for preview and for output to PDF.

If only PDF is needed, skip the preview.